# how to insert json ajax response array result value into my-sql?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, api

This is API result like multiple sale_id pass using array

`Array ( [0] => 37 [1] => 38 [2] => 39 [3] => 40 )`

Now i want to insert it to my table but don't know how to insert sale_id value  into table?
Using loop or any of method?

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Do you want to insert it into one row as a string or in multiple row separately.

Comment: insert as seperate row like 37

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store just the result in db column. Convert response array to json string using json json and store in one column.

```
$stringData = json_encode($arrayData);
```

OR loop array data to build Batch insert mysql query

```
$yourArray=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
if(is_array($yourArray)){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (field_name) values ";

    $valuesArr = array();
    foreach($yourArray as $row){           

        $valuesArr[] = "('$row')";
    }

    echo $sql .= implode(',', $valuesArr);

    mysql_query($sql) or exit(mysql_error()); 
}
```

Query will be like

```
INSERT INTO table (field_name) values VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this above by using this code

```
$sale_ids=[37,38,39,40];
$query='';
foreach ($sale_ids as $sale_id) {
      $query[]=['sale_id'=>$sale_id];
     }
if ($query!='')
DB::table('tableName')->insert($query);
```

I thing this will help you.